# writing a loop and the integrate function

Tags: r, integral

I would like to calculate integral from two columns in my data frame
the integral is based on a function; 1/x, I quess I need to write a loop . Can you help with writing a loop and the integrate function?

This is the sample data frame;

```
upper_concentration<-c(1:200, 1)
lower_concentration<-upper_concentration*0.9
df = data.frame(upper_concentration,lower_concentration)

for (i in 1:(length(df))){
   integral <- function (x) {1/df$upper_concentration}
   result <- integrate(integral, lower = df$upper_concentration, upper =upper_concentration*0.9)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `integrate` function will perform the integral for the full range.

```
lower <- 1
upper <- 200
integral <- function (x) {1/x}

result <- integrate(integral, lower, upper)
```

Now, if you want the integral for each portion of the dataframe then a loop is necessary.

```
result<-vector(list, length=nrow(df))  #initialize an empty vector
integral <- function (x) {1/x}

for (i in 1:(nrow(df))){
    result[[i]] <- integrate(integral, df$lower_concentration[i], df$upper_concentration[i])
 }
```

Comment: I'd suggest `result <- vector("list", nrow(df))`